# Showing that the Gamma Function has Poles by "staying close" to its integral identity $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

Consider the canonical definition of the gamma function on $\mathbb{C}$:

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$

**Problem:** How can one show that $\Gamma$ has poles for $z=0, -1, \ldots$?

One proof I've seen uses various facts about the gamma function to show that:

$$\Gamma(z) = {\Gamma(z + n + 1) \over z(z+1) \ldots (z +n)}$$

This clearly shows the result in question; however, this latter representation of the gamma function is "far away" from the former, canonical representation.

**Question:** Is there a way to show that $\Gamma$ has poles by sticking close to its canonical representation (i.e., by using facts about integrals and so forth)?

Comment: Straight from the integral definition (using integration by parts), we get $$\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$$ which leads to the formula you've listed by a quick induction. How much closer to the integral representation do you want?

Comment: iirc for a function to have a pole $z$ you need to be defined on a neighbourhood of $z$. Without the formula you quote, its not clear how to define $\Gamma$ for $\Re z\leq 0$, and so its not clear how you could have asked the question.

Comment: There is a much-less-elementary way to see something about poles by considering the Gamma function as a value of the meromorphic continuation of the distribution $|x|^s$. In addition to the above quoted formula, there is another argument, using the snake lemma, and using the classification of distributions supported at $0$, etc. Perhaps charming, and certainly informative, but not really so much "closer to the defn", as simply "different from the elementary argument".

Answer (score 1):

The integral representation
$$ \Gamma(z)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{z-1} e^{-x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
holds for any $z:\text{Re}(z)>0$. Over such region the functional relation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$ is a straightforward consequence of integration by parts and Euler's product
$$ \Gamma(s)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n! n^s}{s(s+1)\cdots(s+n)}\tag{2}$$
is a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem (see [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), pages 70+). By $(2)$ the $\Gamma$ function is non-vanishing over $\text{Re}(z)>0$ and by $(1)$ it is holomorphic. The functional relation provides an analytic continuation to the complex plane: for instance, since $\Gamma(z)=1+O(z)$ in a neighbourhood of $z=1$, the Laurent series of $\Gamma(z)$ centered at the origin is given by $\frac{1}{z}+O(1)$, since $\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$. In particular the origin is a simple pole with residue $1$ for the $\Gamma$ function. The same principle leads to the fact that the singularities of the $\Gamma$ function are located at $\{0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}$ and these points are simple poles with residues $\{\frac{1}{0!},-\frac{1}{1!},\frac{1}{2!},-\frac{1}{3!},\ldots\}$.